# Add RelativeLayout or ListView inside Gallery View in Android?

Tags: android, listview, gallery, android-relativelayout

Can someone let me know how to add `RelativeLayout` or `listview` inside `GalleryView`. I have tried by returning `listview` or `RelativeLayout` from the adapter of Gallery but it gives `ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.`

Can someone let me know how to go about it?

Comment: Could you post the code where you declare the LayoutParams of the RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 3):

When you set the LayoutParams of a view, you need to use the specific LayoutParams of the parent view. In your case, you have to use Gallery.LayoutParams as shown here:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(cont);
listView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```